# Problema de almacenamiento de datos

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo un problema de almacenamiento de datos con una tabla de Sql-Server, y no se como solucionarlo.

Para entender el problema primero parto de una tabla auxiliar llamada tbTemporal, en la cual tengo diversos campos: campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4..... hasta Campo21 (alfanuméricos), y Numero1, Numero2, Numero3 ..... hasta Numero10 (numéricos). Los que van informados son los siguientes: campo1, campo2, campo3, campo20, campo21 y Numero1. Adjunto un pantallazo de algunos de estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, campo21 tiene una configuración de VARCHAR(MAX), que por lo que he visto por internet, podría llegar incluso a contener 2 elevado a 32 caracteres.

Me piden actualizar la tabla. La cuestión, es que por Campo1, debidamente ordenado, existen algunos registros duplicados, y hay que eliminarnos y quedarnos con uno solo. Por los campos que informo, tanto Campo2, como Campo3, Campo20 y Numero1, son iguales todos para los registros duplicados, pero Campo21 no, por lo que hay que concatenar toda la información de los registros duplicados por Campo1, y grabarla en dicho registro.

Pues bien, tengo montado un script con transac-Sql, que funciona, pero no va del todo bien. El problema es que para un mismo Campo1 tengo a veces hasta 9 registros, y cuando esto sucede, la información que contiene Campo21 en cada uno de ellos es de 30000 caracteres, por lo que el total de caracteres a grabar sobrepasa los 250000 caracteres, y en la actualización que realizo, tan solo me graba 65535 caracteres, o lo que es lo mismo 2 elevado a 16, y no lo que tenía pensado para un campo tipo VARCHAR(MAX).

¿Porqué me está pasando esto y qué puedo hacer para que mi código funcione como quiero y grabe todos los caracteres de Campo21 en uno solo para un Campo1 que tiene varios registros?.... Adjunto el código del Script, así como otra Query de entrada de datos que me facilitaron para obtener esta información, pero  me da el mismo resultado y no se como solucionar esto.

Gracias de antemano.

Mi código de Script con Transac-Sql es:

```
DECLARE @Campo1 VARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @Campo21 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DestinationID VARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @dest_tbDialCodes VARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @ws_campo1 VARCHAR(250)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Campo1, value Campo21 from tbTemporal
CROSS APPLY string_split(Campo21,',')
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> ''
order by Campo1

OPEN db_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Campo1, @Campo21
SET @ws_campo1 = ''

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 

    IF @Campo1 <> @ws_campo1
        begin
        SET @destinationID = ''
        select @DestinationID = DestinationID from tbMDL where Destination = @Campo1
        SET @ws_campo1 = @Campo1
        end

    if @DestinationID = '' 
        begin
        print 'Destino ' + @Campo1 + ' no encontrado en tbMDL'
        end
    else
        begin
        SET @dest_tbDialCodes = ''
        select @Dest_tbDialCodes = DestinationID from tbDialcodes 
        where destination = @Campo1
        and dialcode = @Campo21
        if @dest_tbDialCodes = ''
            begin
            insert into tbDialcodes
            values (@DestinationID, @Campo1, LTRIM(@Campo21))
            end
        else
            begin
            print 'Destino/DialCode: ' + @Campo1 + '/' + @Campo21 + ' ya está en tbDialCodes'
            end
        end
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Campo1, @Campo21
END
CLOSE db_cursor 
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Asi mismo incluyo una Query que me facilitaron, pero que da el mismo resultado....

```
SELECT Campo1, Campo21=STUFF(
(SELECT ', ' + Campo21 AS [text()]
FROM tbTemporal XT
WHERE XT.Campo1 = T.Campo1
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM tbTemporal T
GROUP BY Campo1;
```

Comment: Antes de empezar ¿Estás seguro que los contenidos no están completos? Es probable que se trunquen al momento de mostrarlos en pantalla pero estén almacenados correctamente. Usa LEN() para verificar la longitud.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, siempre indica la versión del software en el que estás. Algo cambia de MSSQL 2005 a 2019, digamos.

Según [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), ese amigo llega a 2^31-1 **bytes** (nunca dice carácteres) e indica además un límite de 2GB. No es evidente en tu pregunta si estás usando una codificación single-byte o multibyte (y ciertos conjuntos de carácteres van a usar más de un byte para ser representados...). Entonces, no necesariamente tienes 2^31 - 1 carácteres pa guardar, sólo tienes esos bytes.

De hecho, un poco más adelante la misma documentación hace esa aclaración

> A common misconception is to think that CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n), the n defines the number of characters. But in CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n) the n defines the string length in bytes (0-8,000). n never defines numbers of characters that can be stored

Que en español de la calle en Bogotá significa que es común que hagan esa suposición que mencioné (y que se equivoquen en el proceso). Igual, tampoco nos dices cómo estás validando si el registro quedó completo (y `LEN(x)` suele ser la mejor opción) porque el visor de tu cliente de BD seguro se puede quedar corto mostrando ESA tabla.

Igual, algunos usuarios han reportado que el límite se ha ido modificando hacia arriba de versión en versión. En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611394/maximum-size-of-a-varcharmax-variable) usan esta consulta

```
DECLARE @y VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),92681); 

SET @y = REPLICATE(@y,92681);

SELECT LEN(@y)
```

Para validar de qué tamaño queda un varchar(max). Les da como 8GB.